# How to use connect-msolservice with automated credentials?

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server, multi-factor-authentication

The top code block does not work and the bottom does. The bottom prompts for the typical MFA O365 login window "Microsoft Sign in Email or phone" (as pictured below) and I'd like to use the credential parameter of the cmdlet Connect-MsolService. We don't use passwords here, but certs instead and so I'd like to programatically provide the users email address to the Connect-MsolService cmdlet, and do so without the password, the same way that authentication is done with the MFA sign in window. How can this be accomplished?

```
$adminName = "blah@blah.com";
#$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "notneeded" -AsPlainText -Force;

$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $adminName;
Connect-MsolService -Credential $creds; 
$currentDateTime = (GET-DATE);

$lastDirSyncTime =(Get-MsolCompanyInformation).LastDirSyncTime.ToLocalTime();

$timeDifference = $currentDateTime - $lastDirSyncTime;

Write-Host "";
Write-Host "Minutes since the last sync:" $timeDifference.TotalMinutes "minutes.";
```

Below works but opens the MFA auth window pictured below, asking for a login user name

```
Connect-MsolService; 
$currentDateTime = (GET-DATE);

$lastDirSyncTime =(Get-MsolCompanyInformation).LastDirSyncTime.ToLocalTime();

$timeDifference = $currentDateTime - $lastDirSyncTime;

Write-Host "";
Write-Host "Minutes since the last sync:" $timeDifference.TotalMinutes "minutes.";
```

[image: O365 auth window that I want to avoid]

Comment: A colleague just hit a similar issue.  From what I've seen once you run `Connect-MsolService` interactively once, the credentials seem to be remembered & you don't get prompted again, even if you start a new session.  Not sure how long that lasts for though (e.g. presumably it creates a cookie somewhere & that cookie has a lifetime).

Comment: This page shows how to create tokens which can be used instead of credentials; so would likely help in your scenario: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/partnercenter/multi-factor-auth?view=partnercenterps-3.0#ms-online

Comment: Note: MS also now recommend using the `AzureAD` module over the `MSOnline` one; both have the same issue with MFA / the same workaround though - so only mentioning this to save you effort if you're still at the early stages of your project & don't want to have to adapt everything should the old approach be decomissioned.

Comment: can you only do this with partner center? you cant create an auth app directly in an O365 tenant/Azure AD and use that to connect-msolservice?